# How can i make folders session-based accessible?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a folder /video which should only be accessible for users who are logged in. For Authentication I use sessions. If sessions are set correctly, I use chmod('/video', 0755) to make the folder accessible. My problem: everybody has access to that folder now. How can i make folders session-based accessible?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you give read and execute rights to everyone because of the 0755:

- 7: Users have read, write, and execute rights
- 5: The declared user group has read and execute rights
- 5: Others have read and execute rights

You could try `chmod('/video', 0750)`

For more info read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).